# How to change input type to just text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a button but when I press the button I want to change the button to just a text output. I don't want to change the text inside the button. I want to change the button itself into a text.

`<input type="button" id="button1" value="See Answer" onclick="check1();">`

this is my button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function check1() {
          const answer = document.getElementById("question1").innerText;
          const mybutton = document.getElementById("button1");
          if(answer=="Seoul") mybutton.innerText = "CORRECT"
          else mybutton.innerText = "Seoul"
        }
      </script>
```

this is my unfinished version of changing the button into the text "CORRECT" if the answer is correct and changing the button into text "Seoul" if the answer is wrong.

Comment: If you simply replace `innerText` with `value`, it will works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type button and text does not have `innerText`, use value instead:

```js
function check1() {
  const answer = document.getElementById("question1").innerText;
  const mybutton = document.getElementById("button1");
  if(answer=="Seoul") {
        mybutton.parentNode.removeChild(mybutton);
        var t = document.createTextNode("Correct");
        document.body.appendChild(t);}
  else {
        mybutton.parentNode.removeChild(mybutton);
        var t = document.createTextNode("Seoul");
        document.body.appendChild(t);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" value="See Answer" onclick="check1();">

<input id="question1">
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element does not have `innerText` property, use [**`value`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) instead. You also should remove the button and create a text node with the value using [**`createTextNode()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode). Finally insert the created text element after the input element:

```js
function check1() {
  const answer = document.getElementById("question1");
  const mybutton = document.getElementById("button1");
  mybutton.remove();
  var textNode;
  if(answer.value.trim() == "Seoul"){
    textNode = document.createTextNode("CORRECT");
  }
  else textNode = document.createTextNode("Seoul");
  //insert the text node after the answer element
  answer.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, answer.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<input id="question1"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="See Answer" onclick="check1();">
```

Comment: The question is not regarding changing the value of button but to change the button tag to text or div with the text as an answer

Comment: @AyushKatiyar, you are right, updated the answer, +1 your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You can make one element with same text with buttons text, and firstly to hide this element. When you click on button show element and hide the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button field to text field by fetching the element by id and [setattribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) of type to text

```
document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("type","text");
```

To disable the converted text field, you can do it this way.

```
document.getElementById("button1"). disabled = true;
```

The complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check1() {
  //Fetch elements and answers
  const answer = document.getElementById("question1").innerText;
  const mybutton = document.getElementById("button1");

  //Change button to text field with changing its type attriube to text
  mybutton.setAttribute("type","text");

  //Disable the newly created text field
  mybutton.disabled = true;

  if(answer === "Seoul"){
    mybutton.value = "CORRECT";
  }else{
    mybutton.value = "Seoul";
  }
}
</script>
```

Lastly, use Triple equals (===)  instead of Double equals (==) whenever doing comparison. Double equals (==) converts the variable values to the same type before performing comparison. While triple equals (===) does not do any type conversion (coercion) and returns true only if both values and types are identical

Comment: I tried this but this only changed the button into an input textbox that had the value "Seoul" in it. What should I do if I want to change the button into a text that is not editable?